# ¿Cómo hacer login de usuarios, con la contraseña encriptada md5?

Tags: php, mysqli

Este es mi código:

```
<?php
session_start();

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbvasco");

if ( isset($_POST["user"] ) && isset( $_POST["pass"] ) ) {
    $user = $_POST['user']);
    $pass = $_POST['pass']);
    $pass = md5($pass);

    //consulta para obtener el usuario
    $sql1 = "SELECT idUsersProfe FROM users_profesores WHERE (User='$user' OR EMail='$user') AND Passwd='$pass'";
    $query=mysqli_query($connect, $sql1); 
    $res=mysqli_num_rows($query); //Obtene el número de filas de un resultado
    $passDB = mysqli_fetch_array($res); // Obtien una fila de resultados como un array asociativo, numérico, o ambos

    if ($pass == $passDB["Passwd"]) {
        $sql2 = "SELECT User FROM users_profesores WHERE (User='$user' OR EMail='$user') AND Passwd='$pass'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql2);
        $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if ($num_row == "1") {
            $data = mysqli_fetch_array($result); // Obtiene una fila de resultados como un array asociativo, numérico, o ambos
            $_SESSION["user"] = $data["User"];
            echo "1";
        } else {  //fin if num_row
            echo "error";
        }
    } else {  //fin if pass = passDB
        echo "error";
    } 
} else{   //fin if isset
    echo "error";
}

?>
```

Comment: Este código presenta graves problemas de seguridad y es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. No debería usarse de cara al público, tendrías que adaptarlo para solucionar los problemas de seguridad antes (usa sentencias preparadas en lugar de dinámicas)

Answer (score 1):

Tan simple como:

```
if(md5($form_passwd) === $rs["Passwd"]) {
    // hashes coinciden
}
```

Comment: ¿habría algún otro error en el código posteado? aparte de de como tiene la comparación:  if ($pass == $passDB["Passwd"]) {        }

Comment: ¿No has probado tu código? No lo veo mal, se supone funciona, ¿o no es así?

Comment: no loguea el usuario, entra en el else: de datos incorrectos.

Comment: El asunto es que en todos los `else` pones 'error', lo cual dificulta saber **qué else** se ha ejecutado. Por favor especifica mensajes de error diferentes para cada `else`.

Comment: Los datos del formulario de logueo se envian con ajax al archivo que puse publicado, y esta entrando en la parte "datos incorrectos" impresa cuando no recibe ningún data desde donde se compara en el archivo php los datos del form con los de la BD. El echo "1" es el string que recibe el archivo que contiene ajax, desde donde tambien se envian los datos de logueo, y esta entrando en el else cuando no recibe ese string "1" sobre que encontro registro.

Comment: if (data=="1") {
$(location).attr('href','index_docente.php');
 } else {
$("#result").html("<div class='alert alert-dismissible alert-danger'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button><strong>¡Alto!</strong> Datos Incorrectos.</div>");
     }
   }

Comment: Vale. Te entiendo. Debemos saber qué else se ejecuta en tu código PHP para dar con el problema. Asigna un mensaje para cada else y luego, haz un `console.log(data);` en el success del ajax para saber qué else se ha ejecutado. Por ejemplo: `else { echo 'No se han encontrado resultados; }`. Entiendes la idea?

Comment: de acuerdo.....¿antes del if (data=="1") {  }else{ ..... }   O Déspues?

Answer (score 0):

Imagina que en tu base de datos tienes la contraseña ya encriptada y es esta:

> fc7b90ddca8a27b9cb71e301dc027d94

Y en el formulario de por ejemplo un login introducen la contraseña:

```
$passUser = "passdeprueba"; // esto vendría del form.. $_POST["pass"];
```

Solo tienes que hacer la comparación:

```
if(md5($passUser) == $row["pass"]) {
    echo "password correcto";
else {
    echo "password INCORRECTO";
}
```

En la base de datos guardas la contraseña ya encriptada y luego haces las comparaciones

Comment: Si creo que asi lo tengo.......
if (md5($pass) == $passDB["Passwd"]) {

Comment: Los datos del formulario de logueo se envian con ajax al archivo que puse publicado, y esta entrando en la parte "datos incorrectos" impresa cuando no recibe ningún data desde donde se compara en el archivo php los datos del form con los de la BD,